# How to pass some parameters in Subject Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is subject type:

```
public registerFilter: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

I can use it like:

```
this.registerFilter.next("calendarplan");
```

How to modify Subject type to pass additional data like this:

```
this.registerFilter.next("calendarplan", {id: 1, name: "O"});
```

Comment: You can't? I mean you can just `.next` an object. `.next({ value: "calendarplan", options: { id: 1, name: "0" } }`

Comment: So, `next()` allows only one parameters? And you suggest to me use object ?

Comment: Yes, Subjects send objects. Just wrap it in the object like I've shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Subject` is a special type of `Observable`. It does not accept multiple values in `next` method.

You need to redesign your way of sending parameters. Like following:

```
this.registerFilter.next({type: "calendarplan", filter_params: {id: 1, name: "O"}});
```

For furher reading: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject